# Expanding function on [0,1] using Legendre polynomials

Tags: fourier-series, legendre-polynomials

A quick question. Given a boundary condition that a function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n P_{2n+1}(x)$ , which is defined for $x$ in $[0,1]$, not for $-1$ to $1$.

I know the standard Fourier- Legendre Series, but in this question, the Legendre polynomials only have its odd terms, together with x only defined in $[0,1]$. In this case, how to write $f(x)$ in terms of integral from 1 to 0 ?

Comment: A few comments. I guess the boundary condition is $f(0)=0$ ? What are the other assumptions over $f$ ? Continuous ? (Answers to this question should be added to your question.) Also, if the odd Legendre Polynomials are still orthogonal over $[0,1]$, the expansion coefficients of a continuous function can be computed using integrals like you would normally do for $[-1,1]$. To be sure we can claim the equality between the expansion and the function $f$, you have to show they form a basis of all the possible $f$ (depending on the assumptions you have over this function).

Comment: The question is actually a Laplace's equation independence of theta on a hemisphere, and after using cosine as substitution, we have a Legendre equation. The BC is actually u(r,pi/2)=0, f=u(1,phi) thus it is indeed f(0)=0 after substitution.

Comment: My idea is to use SL-problem on [0,1], and the conditions satisfy SL-problem. After that, I claim by SL-orthogonality, we can write any proper f(x) in generalised fourier with Legendre polynomial of odd terms as eigenfunctions, and thus the coefficient can be written as the integral

Comment: But unlike the general result of Legendre polynomial, I can't really solve one of the integral on [0,1], so the solution involves two integrals. Is it fine?

Comment: I did not get the last comment with the two integrals. You should definitely edit your question to include all the information one could need to answer it properly without having to guess.